# pdo connection in php file executed in terminal does not work

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have a php file that if executed in the browser works just fine but when I execute it in the terminal,

> php
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/site_name/update_db.php

the pdo include and connection do not seem to work because I get the error

> could not find driverPHP Fatal error: 
>   Call to a member function prepare() on
>   a non-object in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/site_name/update_db.php
>   on line 8

**update_db.php**

```
include("roc/include/connection.php");
$db = new PDOConnectionFactory();
$conn = $db->getConnection();

//prepare for utf8 characters
$sql = 'SET NAMES utf8';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute();

$sql = 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute();
//**************************


 $sql = 'update video SET
status=? WHERE file_name=?';
$stmt6 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt6->execute(array('1','5cca985383047644f51c4f31d906c8f8'));
```

**Anyone have any ideas?**

Comment: I think it may be a combination of the directory that you are executing from and your php include path setting.

Comment: it's also possible that cli php is using a different php.ini file than the http version. If the pdo module is loaded in the main php.ini and not in the cli version, this will happen.

Comment: how do you find out where cli php.ini file is?

Comment: @Scarface: to see which php.ini is used execute this script in cli mode: `<?php phpinfo();` and look for value of `Loaded Configuration File => /path/to/your/php.ini`

Comment: the pdo was indeed using a different php.ini file, lazyone or spurious, make an answer and I will upvote and accept.

Comment: I installed pdo and changed connection to connect to 127.0.0.1 and it works

Comment: The connection in my connection.php file that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic has been Solved. Read Comments.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like permission issue. When you execute script from the browser, executing user is usually your web server (i.e. Apache) when you execute it from the console - logged-in user is executing it.

Comment: The whole site_name directory is 777.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, on the command line you need to set a path or use absolute paths.

Comment: How do you do that? What does that mean?

Comment: [set_include_path](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) but the safest thing would be to use an absolute path for your include statement like `include("/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/site_name/roc/include/connection.php");`

Comment: ... or use `required` instead of `include` (at least to investigate this moment) -- it will give you an error if file is not found with some more info.

Comment: Thanks any Idg, turns out to be wrong php.ini, I installed pdo and changed connection to connect to 127.0.0.1 and it works